# How to clear Recently Used Reports in Crystal Reports 2011

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2011

Is there a stackoverflow forum, which could answer Crystal Reports 2011 queries?

I'm looking for instructions on how to clear the Recently Used Reports list on the first page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is the right place to ask.

You can clear the recent files using regedit.

Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Business Objects\{version}\Crystal Reports\Recent Files` and change the `FileCount` value to `0`.

It's a bit fiddley but you could create a `.reg` file to do this with a double click.

Comment: For Crystal Reports 2011 (14.0.x), the `FileCount` key is in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SAP BusinessObjects\Suite XI 4.0\Crystal Reports\Recent Files`